# Classic ASP TLS 1.2 issue

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working with a classic asp script that I inherited.  I'm trying to connect with TLS 1.2, but am having issues.  I get a 500 Error when I try to run the following:

```
<%

Const   WinHttpRequestOption_SecureProtocols = 9
Const   SecureProtocol_SSL2 = 8, SecureProtocol_SSL3 = 32, _
        SecureProtocol_TLS1 = 128, SecureProtocol_TLS1_1 = 512, _
        SecureProtocol_TLS1_2 = 2048

Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

objHttp.option(9) = 128
objHttp.open "GET", "https://howsmyssl.com/a/check", false
objHttp.Send
Response.Write objHttp.responseText 
Set objHttp = Nothing 
%>
```

If I eliminate the option(9), it runs just fine, but doesn't connect via TLS 1.2.  The server registry has already been updated and a check of the server via SSL Labs (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) shows that the server is all set for TLS 1.2.

This is on a Windows 2008 Server (Not R2).  Any ideas on how I can get things to run TLS 1.2?

Comment: Are you sure [TLS 1.2 is installed](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/microsoftsecure/2017/07/20/tls-1-2-support-added-to-windows-server-2008/)?

Comment: Not 100%.  I know that when I run the test on SSL Labs, it show that TLS 1.2 works, but I just can't use it programatically.  How do I check for sure?

Comment: I don't think you have a whole lot of options with Windows 2008 since the patch to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 support for WinHttp,  [KB3140245](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in), was only offered for Windows 2008 R2 and higher.

Comment: I've got TLS 1.2 working on the server, I'm just having issues with accessing it programatically in the Classic ASP script.  Could this be an IIS setting somewhere?

Comment: We are looking to turn off TLS 1.1 and then overwriting the winhttp.dll on the server with a copy of winhttp.dll from a windows server 2016 server to see if that is a temporary fix... Mind you this is a 2008 R2 machine... Will update shortly.

Comment: After much searching, we implemented a Linux Proxy Server which allowed us to send out using TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 3):

WinHttp on Windows 2008/Vista doesn't support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.  If I use Object Browser in Visual Studio to examine a winhttp.dll from a Windows 2008 machine you will notice in the screenshot below the WinHttpRequestSecureProtocols enum doesn't have `SecureProtocol_TLS1_1` or `SecureProtocol_TLS_1_2`.

[image]

Compare this to a Windows 10 machine:

[image]

[KB3140245](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in) allows a registry change to default WinHttp to TLS 1.1 and/or TLS 1.2, doing so gets around the issue of not being able to set TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 programmatically, but there is no update for Windows 2008, only Windows 2008 R2 and higher. Windows Server 2016 supports this natively, so I would recommend updating to Server 2016 if possible.

Comment: After updating the registry, do you have to reboot the machine in order for it to take effect? I tried restarting the website, but that wasn't enough.