# Using classic ASP, how to fetch or screenscrape meta tags of html page?

Tags: asp-classic

Using the following code, I can reach the site, grab the data, but I cannot obtain the meta title tag. Surprisingly, I searched for methods to obtain meta tags while screenscraping with classic ASP and only found a couple of example, neither of which I could get to work.

Any assistance?

```
rss_url = "https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2019/06/opal-fossils-reveal-new-species-dinosaur-australia-fostoria/"

Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
objHTTP.Open "GET", rss_url, False
objHTTP.Send

if objHTTP.Status = 200 Then sdata = BinaryToString(objHTTP.ResponseBody)

Set objHTTP = Nothing      

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "<meta.*property=""og:image"".*content=""(.*)"".*\/>"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
Set matches = regEx.Execute(sdata)
if matches.Count > 0 then
KeywordAl = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
response.write "Image = " & KeywordAl&"<hr>"
end if
```

I included the BinaryToString Function just to be complete:

```
Function BinaryToString(byVal Binary)
    '--- Converts the binary content to text using ADODB Stream

    '--- Set the return value in case of error
    BinaryToString = ""

    '--- Creates ADODB Stream
    Dim BinaryStream
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    '--- Specify stream type.
    BinaryStream.Type = 1 '--- adTypeBinary

    '--- Open the stream And write text/string data To the object
    BinaryStream.Open
    BinaryStream.Write Binary

    '--- Change stream type to text
    BinaryStream.Position = 0
    BinaryStream.Type = 2 '--- adTypeText

    '--- Specify charset for the source text (unicode) data.
    BinaryStream.CharSet = "UTF-8"

    '--- Return converted text from the object
    BinaryToString = BinaryStream.ReadText
End Function
```

Comment: "meta title tag" as in `<meta name="title"` is not really a thing, and the page you're trying to scrape doesn't have it. Are you instead trying to get the `<title></title>` on the page? Your question doesn't make sense, please clarify.

Comment: I thought the <title> tag is no longer in the web standards?? That's why I don't want to try to grab it.The meta title tag is, or at least a version of it. I looked on that page and <meta name="title" content="title of article">does not exist, but <meta name="og:title" content="title of article"> does exist. I've noticed most sites, though, do have <meta name="title" content="title of article">.

Comment: `<title>` isn't going anywhere, where did you hear otherwise? Just use that. If you do want to do stick with grabbing something in a `meta` tag, in the page you're trying to scrape... it's NOT this: `<meta name="title" content="title of article">`. It's also NOT this: `<meta name="og:title" content="title of article">`. It IS this: `<meta property="og:title" content="Gem-like fossils reveal stunning new dinosaur species"/>`. `property=` vs `name=`. Note that different websites might use slightly different syntax, you will have to check carefully...

Comment: I'm getting so many mixed answers on this based on my search. This [post is the most referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22350105/whats-the-difference-between-meta-name-and-meta-property) in this forum. Thoughts?

Comment: Just to follow up on @thirtydot , see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title and you'll see that `<title>` is still very much part of the spec and not going anywhere

Comment: Now that we've established both name and property are both correct tags, is it possible to scrape this data? In my example, even when I switch <meta name="title" content ="something here" /> to <meta property="og:title" content ="something here" /> I am still unable to scrape the content. Any advice?

Comment: Update your question with your current code. There is probably a very small error in your code.

Comment: @ThirtyDot, can you get that NationalGeographic to load via the xmlhttprequest? I'm able to get it to work with other links, but not that link. I also have a problem with links on nbcnews.com. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not going to investigate properly, but some sites will block requests if you don't set a "normal" `User-Agent` or "acceptable" `Referer` header (HTTP request header). Compare the HTTP headers that your web browser sends with what your code is sending. Use tools such as Wireshark. Consider using a more modern language such as Python which will make this stuff easier. I'm sure there are guides out there on this stuff. Good luck.

Comment: I checked fiddler and used the same user agent I send:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36. I updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Function GetTextFromUrl(url)
  Dim oXMLHTTP
  Dim strStatusTest
  Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
  oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
  oXMLHTTP.Send
  If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    GetTextFromUrl = oXMLHTTP.responseText
  End If
End Function

Dim sResult : sResult = GetTextFromUrl("https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/2019/06/opal-fossils-reveal-new-species-dinosaur-australia-fostoria/")

Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "<meta.*property=""og:image"".*content=""(.*)"".*\/>"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
Set matches = regEx.Execute(sResult)
if matches.Count > 0 then
  KeywordAl = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
  response.write "Image = " & KeywordAl&"<hr>"
end if
```

For me this outputs for that page:

Image = https://www.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/science/2019/05/22/gemstone-dino/og-fostoria_final.ngsversion.1559624211907.adapt.1900.1.jpg

edit: Added some debugging info here. Try this snippet and see what it says about your TLS version - it is possible this site refuses connections below a certain TLS level.

```vb
Set objHttp = Server.CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1") 
objHttp.open "GET", "https://howsmyssl.com/a/check", False 
objHttp.Send 
Response.Write objHttp.responseText 
Set objHttp = Nothing 
Response.End
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm receiving an error on oXMLHTTP.Send: "A security error occured". I switched to 6.0 and received the error: "The system cannot locate the resource specified." What could this mean? I can access other https sites so I don't think it's a certificate issue.

Comment: Can you access other URLs with the above code from different websites? As 3.0 and as 6.0? If you can then we know it's an issue with this specific URL/site. If you can't access any URLs then we know the issue is with using the ServerXMLHTTP component.

Comment: I can access other sites, even ssl sites. But this has been going on since June 3 when I started this post.

Comment: Did you try "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0"? Or "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"? The first of these works for me, but the second generates the error you mentioned.

Comment: I added a little snippet above in my answer, can you try this to confirm your TLS level? It could be the site refuses certain TLS levels.

Comment: TLS 1.0. Is there a way to override this without installing 1.2??

Comment: Classic ASP uses the default TLS of the server it is running on, but some people have tried to set the level, e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497058/classic-asp-tls-1-2-issue but unless it is installed you're going to be out of luck. What server is this running on? If you want to install it then see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi ?

Comment: I have 2008 R1. I was told it's impossible to add tls1.2 to R1.

Comment: Ah, that might be the case. I checked the National Geographic domain and they don't accept TLS1.0 connections: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.nationalgeographic.com 
TLS 1.3 No, 
TLS 1.2 Yes, 
TLS 1.1 Yes, 
TLS 1.0 No. 
So I guess this is the problem. I'm sorry but I don't know a way around that :(

Comment: I have another server that has tls 1.2 but I cannot run a full site on it. What if I use a PUT request and then run the XHR on the other server and grab that via JSON or another method?

Comment: So I've made progress by using a different server with 1.2. But my regex is not getting the data I need on this page that I'm simply using to test: https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/ex-minneapolis-officer-who-killed-justine-damond-sentenced-12-5-n1013926  Do you know a better regex or maybe even XPath to obtain title and image or og:title and og:image? BTW, thank you for your help. If you make an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Hmm, try this? https://regex101.com/r/5s8GeB/1 -- \"og:image\"\s+content=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)